# foreach loop in php get invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I get "Invalid argument supplied" when using the following code. I can successfully parse an ip address and port number but i dont know how to get more than one at a time. My foreach loop is not working. Any ideas?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$dom_results = $xml->xpath("/html/body/div[@id='subpagebgtabs']/div[@id='container']/table[@id='listtable']");

$ip_address = $dom_results[0]->tr->td[1]->span;
$ip_post = $dom_results[0]->tr->td[2];

$address_parts = $ip_address.":".$ip_post;

foreach ($address_parts as $address_full){
    echo $address_full . "<br>";
}
```

$Dom_Results Output

```
["tr"]=>
    array(50) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["class"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["rel"]=>
          string(7) "9054676"
        }
        ["comment"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#56 (0) {
        }
        ["td"]=>
        array(8) {
          [0]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#57 (2) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(2) {
              ["class"]=>
              string(20) "leftborder timestamp"
              ["rel"]=>
              string(10) "1309047901"
            }
            ["span"]=>
            string(10) "2 minutes"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#58 (1) {
            ["span"]=>
            string(13) "122.72.10.201"
          }
          [2]=>
          string(3) "80"
```

Comment: `$address_parts` doesn't look like an array to me.

Comment: Well I can see that $adress_parts is not array.

Comment: Did you know $address_parts should be an array?

Comment: @todda.speot.is i did a var_dump on $dom_results and updated my post. can you explain how i can do it now to return all ip address and ports numbers?

Comment: What do you want to do with ip address here ? If you explain that we could get you an answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
// If results are found
if ( ! empty($dom_results) )
  // Loop through each result. Based on your XPath query, the $dom_results
  // contains tables. This loops through the rows of the first table.
  foreach ( $dom_results[0]->tr as $row )
  {
    $ip_address = $row->td[1]->span;
    $ip_post = $row->td[2];

    // Output the address
    echo $ip_address . ":" . $ip_post . "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: I think this is what I need but it only returns 1 of the ip address on the page. Is there a way to make it return all of them at one time?

Comment: @sarsar - I've updated the answer to loop through each table row (TR) as opposed to each table. That's probably going to solve the problem. It wasn't quite clear (and still isn't) how the data is stored in the table(s) you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want to extract all the ip address and port numbers and concatenate it like

ipaddress:port

So try this

```
foreach($dom_results as $dom) {
  $ip = $dom->tr->td[1]->span;
  $port = $dom->tr->td[2];
  $address = $ip . ":". $port;
  echo $address . "<br />";
}
```